# Strange :id in :path with Mongoid-Paperclip — /4f8b/5a82/ef1a/7750/b800/0077/

Tags: mongoid, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've just upgraded from Rails 3.1.3 to 3.2.3 and noticed that browser doesn't show images anymore. So I looked to images path and it is `/system/photos/images/4fce/1fb6/3ee5/1d01/a800/0006/original/IMG_2842new2.jpg?1338908598` for example. There is no `:path` declaration in model, so it should use default `:rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename`.

The key thing the images aren't shown is that `:id` parameter `4fce1fb63ee51d01a8000006` is stored in DB devided by slashes (`/`) into 4-symbol groups: `4fce/1fb6/3ee5/1d01/a800/0006`, but  the folder is named as it sould be, `4fce1fb63ee51d01a8000006`. That's pretty strange.

I use

```
mongo (1.6.2) 
mongoid (2.4.10) 
paperclip (3.0.4) 
mongoid-paperclip (0.0.7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake, didn't notice that when I did updates Paperclip updated too and that version 3.0 requires `:path` and `:url` options to be passed explicitly:

```
:path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
:url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
```